# Losing language character with nusoap

Tags: php, encoding, nusoap

I cant successfuly save data received with nusoap server with right coding. Language characters (Czech) are always replaced with question mark. Iam using PHP 5.3 and nusoap 0.9.5. I tried replacing every ISO-8859-1 with UTF-8 in nusoap source code but I cant make this work.
Any advices would be much aprriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NuSOAP always uses ISO-8859-1 for the WSDL.  This means that identifiers 
in the WSDL, e.g. method and parameter names, must be ISO-8859-1.  There 
is no attempt in NuSOAP to support UTF-8 within WSDL

This link would be helpful to you http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.php.nusoap.general/3630

Answer (score 0):

May be [utf8_encode](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) could help you (before you safe the data).